# Runs and Autocorrelation test

Tags: randomness, statistical-test

I have the book "Handbook of applied cryptography". [In there](https://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap5.pdf#page=15) we have example for random tests.

I have bits sequence `[11100 01100 01000 10100 11101 11100 10010 01001]*4` length on this sequence n = 160. And I need test this sequence in order to understand this sequence is random or not. And problem with understanding this example.

Runs test
I understand how they got

$ e_i=\frac{n-i+3}{2^i+2}$

For
$k=1 \ \ e_1=\frac{160-1+3}{2^3} \ \  B_1 = 25 \ \ G_1 = 8$

$k=2 \ \ e_1=\frac{160-2+3}{2^4} \ \  B_2 = 4 \ \ G_2 = 20$

$k=3 \ \ e_1=\frac{160-3+3}{2^5} \ \  B_3 = 5 \ \ G_3 = 12$

$k=4 \ \ e_1=\frac{160-4+3}{2^6} \ \ \varnothing $

And the question is how they got B and G?

Autocorrelation test. 
In the book they write just (autocorrelation test) If d = 8, then A(8) = 100. The value of the statistic X5 is 3.8933. How they calculate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the runs test [example on page 182-183](https://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap5.pdf), partition the sequence into blocks and gaps without a block appearing next to a block and without a gap appearing next to a gap. Thus

`111 000 11 000 1 000 1 0 1 00 111 0 1111 00 1 00 1 00 1 00 1111 000 11...`

there are 81 groupings in total. Of these $B_1=25$ of them are `1`, $B_2=4$ of them are `11`, $B_3=5$ of them are `111`, $G_1=8$ of them are `0`, $G_2=20$ of them are `00` and $G_3=12$ of them are `000`. There are also 7 instances of `1111` which we do not count.

In the autocorrelation test we look at equation (5.5) on page 182:
$$X_5=2\frac{A(d)-\frac{n-d}2}{\sqrt{n-d}}$$
then with $n=160$, $d=8$ we have $A(8)=100$ and so
$$X_5=2\times\frac{100-\frac{160-8}2}{\sqrt{160-8}}=3.89331.$$

The $d=8$ here is chosen arbitrarily for the example, $A(8)$ is calculated by lining up the first 152 terms of the sequence with the last 152. Thus

`11100011000100010100111011110010010010011110001100...`
`00010001010011101111001001001001111000110001000100...`

and counting where the entries are different. There are 100 out of 152 positions in total where this is the case.

Comment: Thank you very much i got it!

Comment: Sorry, but how you got the d and A(8)?